# How to access elements in array from Pinia store with Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I want to join an array of strings then do text processing on the resultant string. The first console.log shows a single-dimensional array. I initially was accessing the proxy directly then switched to using toRaw. I've tried using a watcher (deep/non-deep) and computed property. I also tried restructuring the Pinia code as I was using a computed property to access the store instead of storeToRefs initially. Any attempt to access an element results in undefined (e.g. summariesRaw[0]). The for loop doesn't begin. "filteredSummaries" is empty in Vue dev tools. When I was using the computed property instead, it would suddenly work sometimes after saving in the code editor and causing a hot-reload.

```
const store = useMainStore()
const { gameSummaries } = storeToRefs(store)
const stopWords = ["test"]
const filteredSummaries = ref('')

// const filteredSummaries = computed(() => {
//   const summariesObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameSummaries.value))
//   console.log(summariesObj)
//     const joined = summariesObj.join(' ')
//     // Strip HTML tags
//     const stripped = joined.replaceAll(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/gi, "")
//     // Strip URLs
//     const stripped2 = stripped.replaceAll(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '')
//     // Remove stop words
//     const filtered = stripped2.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\b('+stopWords.join('|')+')\\b', 'g'), '')
//     console.log(filtered)
//     return filtered
// })

watch(gameSummaries, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  const summariesRaw = toRaw(newValue)
  console.log(summariesRaw)
  for (const e of summariesRaw) {
    console.log(e)
  }
    const joined = summariesRaw.join(' ')
    // Strip HTML tags
    const stripped = joined.replaceAll(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/gi, "")
    // Strip URLs
    const stripped2 = stripped.replaceAll(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '')
    // Remove stop words
    const filtered = stripped2.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\b('+stopWords.join('|')+')\\b', 'g'), '');
    console.log(filtered)
    filteredSummaries.value = joined
}, { deep: true })
```

The Pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useMainStore = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => ({
    gameSummaries: []
  }),
  actions: {
    setGameSummaries(summaries: string[]) {
      this.gameSummaries = summaries
    }
  }
})
```

Result of the first console.log:[image: console.log(summariesObj]

Comment: try add `immediate: true` in watch options

Comment: @TachibanaShin Just tried; it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you try using `computed`?
`const filteredSummaries = computed(() => {
  // Logic filter goes here
})`